# React beautiful Dnd - Invariant failed: Cannot find droppable entry with id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, droppable, react-beautiful-dnd

[image]

I have a list of droppable items created with mapping a table, but when I try to add a new droppable it throws this error, Could anyone help with this problem please